# How to import Storybook component in Turborepo - Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, monorepo, turborepo

I am working on monorepo setup with `turborepo` combined with `Vue` & `Storybook` with below folder structure.
Currently I am unable to import storybook components in my Vue app. How can I do it?

- apps/
- - app1/
- - app2/
- package/
- - storybook/
- - hooks/
- package.json
- package-lock.json

I want to import storybook components from package in my Vue app.

Expected result -

```
<template>
 <div>
   <my-custom-button />
 </div>
</template>
<script>
 import MyCustomComponent from 'storybook';
 export default {
   components: {
     MyCustomComponent
   }
 }
</script>
```